# Problem to change en-US culture to fa-IR culture in windows form application in window 10 64 bit

Tags: cultureinfo, culture

The culture of windows form application doesn't change, despite using the correct code (I think of course).

In the Program.cs file in the win form application I try to change the current culture from en-US to fa-IR and I use these codes:

```cs
CultureInfo culture =  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("Fa-IR");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;  
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;  
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

But after running the program, nothing happened. The current culture is still en-US!. Let me also say this, I don't change the culture program anywhere else.
[image: not change culture]

Answer (score 0):

I thought that after changing the culture of the system, the language of the system should change as well. While I was wrong. By adding the following code I was able to change the Windows language to Farsi.

```cs
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void InitializePersianCulture() {

    var culture = new CultureInfo("fa-ir");
    var info = culture.DateTimeFormat;

    var calendar = new PersianCalendar();
    info.Calendar = calendar;
    var field = typeof(CultureInfo).GetField("Calendar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (field != null)
        field.SetValue(culture, "fa-ir");

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = info;
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat = info;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.